# scala mutable.Map put/get handles null's in an unexpected way?

Tags: scala

I know one is not supposed to use nulls in scala but sometimes when interoperating with Java it happens. The way a scala mutable map handles this seems off though:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable

scala> val m: mutable.Map[String, String] = mutable.Map.empty
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] = Map()

scala> m.put("Bogus", null)
res0: Option[String] = None

scala> m.get("Bogus")
res1: Option[String] = Some(null)

scala> m.getOrElse("Bogus", "default")
res2: String = null
```

I would have expected `m.get` to return `None` in this case. Almost seems like a bug, like somewhere in the code there was a `Some(v)` instead of `Option(v)`

Is there discussion w/r/t to changing this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

> I would have expected m.get to return None in this case.

Why? `None` would mean the key `"Bogus"` is not in the map, but you just put it in (with value `null`).

Java's `Map` API has problems distinguishing "the value for this key is `null`" from "this key is not in the map", but Scala's doesn't.

Comment: Might I suggest a minor clarification? It's rather the `Map#get` method that has problems distinguishing "the value is null" vs "key not in map", but the `Map#containsKey` always worked fine, so maybe it's a bit unfair to judge the *whole Map API* too harshly, it's only the `Map#get` that is a bit weird.

Comment: I also had in mind "For example, some implementations prohibit null keys and values" :)

Comment: Oh, do they? Sorry, I was not aware of that little inconsistency. Alright then, let's blame the entire API :D

Comment: And things like "(A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports null values.)"

Answer (score 1):

`Null` is subtype of `String`:

```
scala> implicitly[Null <:< String]
res3: Null <:< String = <function1>
```

Therefore `null` is a valid `String` value:

```
scala> val s: String = null
s: String = null
```

If you want to store a `null` as a `String` in a map, it's your good right.

---

Compared to Java's `Map#get` (let's call it `javaLikeGet`), the Scala's `get` behaves roughly as follows:

```
def get(k: K) = if (containsKey(k)) { 
  Some(this.javaLikeGet(k)) 
} else { 
  None 
}
```

and not like what you have assumed:

```
def get(k: K) = Option(this.javaLikeGet(k))
```

The latter version (presumably what you thought) would get a `null` for an existing key, pass it to `Option(...)`, and return `None`. But the former version (which imitates how the real implementation works) would notice that the key exists, and wrap the `null` returned by `javaLikeGet` into a `Some`.

The simple and consistent rule is:

> If the key `k` exists, then `get(k)` returns `Some[V]`, otherwise it returns `None`.

This is much less surprising than the strange behavior of Java's `get` that returns `null` in two entirely different situations.

---

This is the Billion-Dollar Mistake, but Scala is not the language that is likely to fix it, because it has to interop with Java. My guess is that there is and will be no discussion about changing this behavior, at least not until something fundamentally changes in the entire programming landscape.

Comment: I think my main issue is that semantically, scala has designed its Map#get to be Option-like. The surprise comes from the fact that `Option(null)` returns `None` and this does not.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Think of it this way: compared to Java's `get` (call it `javaLikeGet`, Scala's `get` is something like `def get(k: K) = if (containsKey(k)) { Some(this.javaLikeGet(k)) } else { None }` instead of `def get(k: K) = Option(this.javaLikeGet(k))`. It's made this way to be *less* surprising. And it works, because, for example, I am *less surprised* that Scala's `Map` does not exhibit same weird behavior as Java's Map.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I've updated my answer, added explanation why it returns `Some(null)` instead of `None`.